# X11 evdev mouse generates duplicate events

Tags: linux, mouse, xorg, udev

Lately my x11 server started registering several duplicate mouse click events per single click.

I've tried upgrading xorg server and drivers, but it didn't help. Using different mouse doesn't help as well, all mouses I tried work fine on other PC.

The only change I remember before it started to act up is udev update, but maybe there was something else as well.

This how it looks in `xev`:

```
Single left button click, registered twice:

ButtonPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0x2b5, subw 0x0, time 16520254, (109,94), root:(860,523),
    state 0x0, button 1, same_screen YES
ButtonRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0x2b5, subw 0x0, time 16520277, (109,94), root:(860,523),
    state 0x100, button 1, same_screen YES
ButtonPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0x2b5, subw 0x0, time 16520293, (109,94), root:(860,523),
    state 0x0, button 1, same_screen YES
ButtonRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0x2b5, subw 0x0, time 16520317, (109,94), root:(860,523),
    state 0x100, button 1, same_screen YES

Single mid button click, registered once:

ButtonPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0x2b5, subw 0x0, time 16533430, (103,95), root:(854,524),
    state 0x0, button 2, same_screen YES
ButtonRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0x2b5, subw 0x0, time 16533438, (103,95), root:(854,524),
    state 0x200, button 2, same_screen YES


Single mid button click, registered 3 times:

ButtonPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0x2b5, subw 0x0, time 16534494, (104,99), root:(855,528),
    state 0x0, button 2, same_screen YES
ButtonRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0x2b5, subw 0x0, time 16534502, (104,99), root:(855,528),
    state 0x200, button 2, same_screen YES
ButtonPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0x2b5, subw 0x0, time 16534566, (104,99), root:(855,528),
    state 0x0, button 2, same_screen YES
ButtonRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0x2b5, subw 0x0, time 16534573, (104,99), root:(855,528),
    state 0x200, button 2, same_screen YES
ButtonPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0x2b5, subw 0x0, time 16534582, (104,99), root:(855,528),
    state 0x0, button 2, same_screen YES
ButtonRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0x2b5, subw 0x0, time 16534598, (104,99), root:(855,528),
    state 0x200, button 2, same_screen YES
```

`Xorg.0.log`:

```
[ 16110.707] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/event3)
[ 16110.707] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[ 16110.707] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech USB Optical Mouse'
[ 16110.707] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: always reports core events
[ 16110.707] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[ 16110.707] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Vendor 0x46d Product 0xc018
[ 16110.707] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found 3 mouse buttons
[ 16110.707] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
[ 16110.707] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found relative axes
[ 16110.707] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
[ 16110.707] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Configuring as mouse
[ 16110.707] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Adding scrollwheel support
[ 16110.707] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[ 16110.707] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[ 16110.707] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6.3/2-1.6.3:1.0/input/input10/event3"
[ 16110.707] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Optical Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 8)
[ 16110.707] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[ 16110.707] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[ 16110.707] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[ 16110.707] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[ 16110.707] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[ 16110.707] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[ 16110.707] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 16110.707] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

`xinput list --long`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    Reporting 5 classes:
        Class originated from: 8
        Buttons supported: 10
        Button labels: Button Left Button Middle Button Right Button Wheel Up Button Wheel Down Button Horiz Wheel Left Button Horiz Wheel Right None None None
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 8
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 8
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 8
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Rel Vert Wheel
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 8

⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 3 classes:
        Class originated from: 4
        Buttons supported: 10
        Button labels: Button Left Button Middle Button Right Button Wheel Up Button Wheel Down Button Horiz Wheel Left Button Horiz Wheel Right None None None
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 4
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 4
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative

⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 5 classes:
        Class originated from: 8
        Buttons supported: 7
        Button labels: Button Left Button Middle Button Right Button Wheel Up Button Wheel Down Button Horiz Wheel Left Button Horiz Wheel Right
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 8
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 8
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 8
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Rel Vert Wheel
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 8
```

- Xorg-server 1.15.1
- XInput 20.0
- evdev 2.8.2

Comment: kernel version?